# Codeigniter, increase database value by value contained in variable

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord

I am using codeigniter, and I have the following function in my model to give points to the user.
It is however not working, rather setting the points column to 0.

This is how it is written in the codeigniter manual. Therefore I have no clue why it is not working...

Thanks

```
function give_points($username,$points)
{
    $this->db->set('points', 'points + $points');
    $this->db->where('username', $username);
    $this->db->update('users'); 
    echo"done";
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have to tell CI specifically to **not** escape the text. Something like:

```
$this->db->set('points', 'points + ' . (int) $points, FALSE);
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this is the cause of your problem, but you are using single quotes, on the following lines :

```
$this->db->set('points', 'points + $points');
```

With this, the `$points` string will be injected as-is, literally, into your SQL query -- it's not its value that's going to be used.

If you want `$points` to be interpolated *(so its value is put in its place, in that string)*, you must use double quotes :

```
$this->db->set('points', "points + $points");
```

For more informations about variable interpolation, see the [**Variables parsing**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing) section of the PHP Manual.

Comment: That producse the query: UPDATE `users` SET `points` = 'points + 1000' WHERE `username` = 'thomas' 

which does not work.. any further ideas?

Comment: Looks like your `points` field in the database is an integer, and you are trying to access it like a string : your query should look like `UPDATE users SET points = 'points + 1000' WHERE username = 'thomas'` ;;; Maybe you have some way of indicating that to CI ? I don't know CI well enough to help more, sorry.

Answer (score -1):

If there is a chance, always check the created SQL query - I do not know how to do it with CI.

However, your `set()` looks flawed.

```
$this->db->set('points', "points + $points");
```

Previously, `$points` was part of the **string**, and not expanded by the contents of `$points`, due to you using a single quote instead of a double quote - see the [manual regarding strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) in PHP.

```
$this->db->set('points', 'points + ' . (int) $points);
```

A slighty better code is the one above, as it defeats possible [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), depending on where `$points` originally comes from.

Comment: Both suggestions produce the query: UPDATE `users` SET `points` = 'points + 1000' WHERE `username` = 'thomas' 

This query is not working...
Thanks

Comment: You have to check the CI manual then. It seems as if CI always puts the given string in `set()` into quotes, so this cannot work that way.